# Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'LeftViewController!'. Why?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class `LeftViewController`:

```
protocol LeftMenuProtocol: class {
func actionOpenHome()
func actionOpenTakeSnap()
func actionOpenGallery()
func actionOpenProfiles()
func actionOpenSettings()
func actionOpenHelp()
func actionOpenContactUs()
func actionOpenBarCode()
func actionOpenAbout()
func actionCloseSideVC()
}

class LeftViewController :  UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var leftMenuDelegate : LeftMenuProtocol?


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

I am trying to add it into another class like this

```
var leftViewController: LeftViewController!

leftViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") 
    self.addChildViewController(leftViewController)
    self.view!.addSubview(leftViewController.view!)
    leftViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)`
```

But getting this error. Somebody knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the variable declaration to

```
leftViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController
```

You need to explicitly cast it.

Comment: Or he can even treat the controller as `UIViewController` since in this portion of code the `LeftViewController` conformance isn't used.